# Saving image binary data to BytesIO

Tags: image, binary-data, python-3.7, bytesio

I am using the following code to write the binary data of an image to Bytes IO:

```
f = io.BytesIO(b'\xff\xd8')
```

When I type in

```
f.getvalue()
```

I get

```
b'\xff\xd8'
```

My question is that how will I know that the image stored in BytesIO is the one whose initial binary data I entered i.e b'\xff\xd8' and not just some random binary data.

Comment: `ff d8` is the signature of a JPEG file, so it looks correct. Why do imagine it may be wrong? https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=JPG&mode=EXT

Comment: I was just curious and needed to confirm